# How can I communicate between Windows 8 and WP8 apps using ssl?

Tags: ssl, notifications, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-phone

I'm considering using either raw notifications (WNS) or sockets for communication between a Windows 8 and WP8 app. I've found some samples for using sockets but my question[s] here are: does WP8 support sending/receiving messages over ssl and, if so, how is it done?

Something I need to be true or find a workaround for is that the Windows 8 app has a permanent IPAddress to which the phone app will send its updates. Typically, a tablet will be running Windows 8 app, always listening for incoming messages; the phone app will periodically send messages.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the WP8 SDK is still under NDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL requires a domain name and a trusted certificate to work. So, it isn't possible to use it with a Windows Store app. What you probably want is some form of encryption to secure that communication. You can achieve that using either a [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) (simpler) or [asymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) key encryption. If you need more details, do some research (Wikipedia is a good start) and ask another question if needed.

By the way, considering all the technical limitations around using a regular PC as "server" (intermittent connection, power offs, firewall, etc), I think it would be more reliable to have a web server in the middle, receiving the messages from the phone app and keeping them until they can be passed onto the Windows Store app.

Comment: Thanks, Mike; I'm looking into WAMS now (Windows Azure Mobile Services) as a possible solution, but am not sure yet if it will be a good fit, either.